# firebase_auth/invalid-phone-number in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

[image] - I'm using phone authentication using firebase in flutter

- When I enter the number and I'll get the otp,
- While Entering to the otp field and verify it shows the  below error in flutter

> I/flutter (27587): [firebase_auth/invalid-phone-number] The format of
> the phone number provided is  incorrect. Please enter the phone number
> in a format that can be parsed into E.164 format. E.164  phone numbers
> are written in the format [+][country code][subscriber number
> including area code]. [  Invalid format. ]

I was tried sevaral ways but it did't work
I was given my verify phone code for firebase given below

```
>  await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
>           phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
>           verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
>           verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
>           codeSent: codeSent,
>           timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
>           codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
```

my verify codesin ui section

```
 await authCalss.verifyPhonenumber(
                                      "+91 ${phonecontroller.text}",
                                      context,
                                      setData);
```

Comment: I think you should not put a space in the phone number. Try this - `"+91${phonecontroller.text}"`

Comment: I'm already tried that way but it won't work

Comment: Can you print it - `"+91${phonecontroller.text}"` ?

Comment: When I print  the result will be +919999900000

Comment: Error in debug console SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17042 Invalid format.

Answer (score 1):

Your Phone Number must be formatted like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the phone number +919999900000. It seems that the problem is in your configuration.

The configuration should look similar to like this:

[image]

Refer to this documentation: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone

Answer (score 0):

I get same error while I did mobile phone authentication in Flutter web

**error: the format of the phone number provided is incorrect. please enter the phone number in a format that can be parsed into e.164 format. e.164 phone numbers are written in the format [+][country code][subscriber number including area code].**

I found authentication with a mobile number sample code [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/)

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: '+44 7123 123 456',
  verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
  verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
  codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {},
  codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
);
```

so, consider in Bharat(India) my mobile number is 9998887770, and my country code is +91

I need to **+91 9998 887 770** format used while verifyPhoneNumber with Firebase authentication.

now in [Textformfield](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) I accept 10 digits only with no space allowed. like I will get 9998887770 format mobile number from my [Textformfield](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html).

The below code will provide formatted mobile number

```
  final phoneNumber = '+91 ${phone.substring(0, 4)} ${phone.substring(4, 7)} ${phone.substring(7)}'; // +91 **** *** *** format mobile number
```

My Own Code // work very well for me

```
  Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber({
    required String phone,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    try {
      final phoneNumber = '+91 ${phone.substring(0, 4)} ${phone.substring(4, 7)} ${phone.substring(7)}'; // +91 **** *** *** format mobile number
      
      await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber ,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
          try {
            final UserCredential? credential = await auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            
          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '${e.message}');
          } catch (e) {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '$e');
          }
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          debugLog('codeAutoRetrievalTimeout : $verificationId');
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? forceResendingToken) {
         // MOVE TO OTP SCREEN 
          pushAndReplace(
            context: context,
            routeName: RouteName.otp,
          );
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException error) {
        
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: '${error.message}',
          );
        },
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
     
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '${e.code}');
    } catch (e) {
     
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '$e');
    }
  }
```

**Hope this will help you**